# symfony doctrine type datetime expected format y-m-d h:i:s

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem in symfony when I try to select some items from database with doctrine.

I run this:

```
$allOrders = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Dieta')->findBy(array('diet_status'=>'active'));
var_dump($allOrders);
```

And I get the following error:

> Could not convert database value "2014-03-03" to Doctrine Type
>   datetime. Expected format: Y-m-d H:i:s

When I insert the date in the database i do it like this:

```
$format = 'd/m/Y';
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $_POST['dietStartDate']);
$dietStartDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dietStartDate = new \Datetime($dietStartDate);

$timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['dietStartDate']));
$timestamp7 = strtotime('+7 days', $timestamp);
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp7);
$dietDateEnd = new \Datetime($datetime);
```

The `$dietStartDate` and `$dietDateEnd` are inserted in a datetime column in database. In the doctrine.yml I have it also declared as datetime.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the value `"2014-03-03"`, it seems that your database column type is `date` but not `datetime`.

Run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update` to check whether there are changes.

Comment: You are very right! I received the database already constructed, and didn't saw that.Thank you my friend, you saved me precious time.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue and i have resolve it by adding the code bellow
the problem is getted because postgres register microseconde when it's different to 0 this produce the isse

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;

Type::overrideType('datetime', 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\VarDateTimeType');
Type::overrideType('datetimetz', 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\VarDateTimeType');
Type::overrideType('time', 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\VarDateTimeType');

Type::overrideType('datetime_immutable', 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\VarDateTimeImmutableType');
Type::overrideType('datetimetz_immutable', 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\VarDateTimeImmutableType');
Type::overrideType('time_immutable', 'Doctrine\DBAL\Types\VarDateTimeImmutableType');
```

you can read more here 
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/known-vendor-issues.html